# Extracting k-means cluster-specific features

Tags: r, heatmap, k-means

I am clustering some gene expression data using k-means in the reduced, PCA space and now I want to extract distinct features that best describe each cluster. These are features that are highly expressed within each cluster.

I've posted below a reproducible example to show my logic and where I've left off.

```
# Create test matrix
test = matrix(rnorm(200), 20, 10)
test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] = test[1:10, seq(1, 10, 2)] + 3
test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[11:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 2
test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] = test[15:20, seq(2, 10, 2)] + 4
colnames(test) = paste("Cell", 1:10, sep = "")
rownames(test) = paste("Gene", 1:20, sep = "")

# plot the inital heatmap
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(t(test))

# preform PCA
pca = prcomp(t(test), center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
rotation = data.frame(pca$x)
plot(rotation[1:3], pch=16, cex=0.6, cex.main=0.9)

# preform Kmeans in PCA space
wss = (nrow(rotation)-1)*sum(apply(rotation,2,var))
for (i in 2:9) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(rotation, centers=i)$withinss)
plot(1:9, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters", ylab="Within groups sum of squares")
km = kmeans(rotation, 2)
cluster_assignment = as.factor(km$cluster)

# plot k-means cluster assignment in PCA space
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(rotation, aes(rotation$PC1, rotation$PC2, color=cluster_assignment, label=rownames(rotation))) + geom_point() + geom_text()

# create a cluster annotation data.frame
n_clusters = length(unique(km$cluster))   
temp_cluster_design_list = list()
for(n in 1:n_clusters){
  temp_cluster_design = data.frame(row.names=row.names(t(test)[cluster_assignment %in% n,]))
  temp_cluster_design$cluster = n 
  temp_cluster_design_list[[n+1]] <- temp_cluster_design
}
cluster_design = do.call(rbind, temp_cluster_design_list)

# cluster_design looks something like this: 
#        cluster
# Cell1        1
# Cell3        1
# Cell5        1
# Cell7        1
# Cell9        1
# Cell2        2
# Cell4        2
# Cell6        2
# Cell8        2
# Cell10       2

# heatmap with cell cluster annotation
PCA_heatmap_data = t(test)[row.names(cluster_design),]
cluster_design$cluster = as.factor(cluster_design$cluster)
pheatmap(PCA_heatmap_data, annotation_row=cluster_design)


# extract out expressed genes from each cluster
for(n in 1:n_clusters) {
    temp_cluster = t(test)[cluster_assignment %in% n,]
#     ??? somehow extract out the expressed gene names specific to each cluster 
}
```

The code above ultimately leaves me with a heatmap that looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAdNT.png). Now, what I'd like to do with each cluster in the heatmap is to extract out gene names that are highly expressed. I ultimately would like to write out a table that looks something like this:

```
GENE      CLUSTER
Gene20    cluster2
Gene19    cluster2
Gene15    cluster2
Gene18    cluster2
Gene16    cluster2
Gene17    cluster2
Gene9     cluster1
Gene8     cluster1
Gene4     cluster1
Gene3     cluster1
...       ...
```

I'm not sure of the best and most efficient way to go about this. I would appreciate any help you could toss my way! Thank you!

**EDIT**

How do we define highly expressed? This I am not quite sure and hoping to get some insight. Perhaps comparing the average for each gene across all cells and comparing that to the average among the cluster? This may work but I think this is prone to be skewed by outliers. Another thought would be to scale each cluster and take genes that are significantly highly expressed?

How would I go about identifying highly expressed genes among clusters that are very similar? For example, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NluV.jpg) heatmap shows three cluster but the red and green clusters are very similar. It appears that Gene9 is cluster2 specific?

Comment: What's the threshold for defining if a gene is highly expressed?

Comment: @Hack-R, that's what I'm struggling with. Would it make sense to compare against the gene average for all cells, and take those within the cluster that are above average? I think that might be the best route to take?

Comment: Sounds right to me

Comment: @Hack-R, do you have any insight as to how to implement this?

Comment: Yes I'm almost done just a sec

Answer (score 1):

```
threshold <- 1
nms       <- as.character()
for(n in 1:n_clusters) {

  for(i in 1:ncol(t(test)[row.names(t(test)) %in% names(cluster_assignment[cluster_assignment == n]),])){
     if(mean(t(test)[row.names(t(test)) %in% names(cluster_assignment[cluster_assignment == n]),i]) > threshold){
             nms <- c(nms, colnames(t(test)[row.names(t(test)) %in% names(cluster_assignment[cluster_assignment == n]),])[i])
     }
  }
  if(n == 1) result <- data.frame(GENE = nms, CLUSTER = rep(n,length(nms))); rm(nms); nms <- as.character()
  if(n >  1) result <- rbind(result, data.frame(GENE = nms, CLUSTER = rep(n,length(nms))))
}

result
```

> ```
>      GENE CLUSTER
> 1   Gene7       1
> 2  Gene11       1
> 3  Gene12       1
> 4  Gene13       1
> 5  Gene14       1
> 6  Gene15       1
> 7  Gene16       1
> 8  Gene17       1
> 9  Gene18       1
> 10 Gene19       1
> 11 Gene20       1
> 12  Gene1       2
> 13  Gene2       2
> 14  Gene3       2
> 15  Gene4       2
> 16  Gene5       2
> 17  Gene6       2
> 18  Gene7       2
> 19  Gene8       2
> 20  Gene9       2
> 21 Gene10       2
> ```

I left the `threshold` as a parameter so that you can define it however you like. In this example I used 1 as the threshold.

Comment: Perfect, this looks like it will work with some tweaking of the threshold param. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hmm, I seem to be throwing an error: `Error in if (mean(t(test)[row.names(t(test)) %in% names(cluster_assignment[cluster_assignment ==  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Not sure why this is.

Comment: @user2117258 I take it that you're getting that error with real data and not the example, correct? The reason for the error is usually that there's an `NA`. So all you have to do is add `na.rm=T` to the `mean` function and hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: this is actually with the simulated example data posted in the OP.  I will update the original post with because I don't believe your method will work for greater than clusters.